# How can I make the flash fire when it is connected with a cord?

Tags: flash, off-camera-flash

I just received the lighting starter kit from Strobist and trying to see if I can make it take a shot before I go to bed tonight :D 
Here is the picture of how I have set it up currently:

[image]

And also this:

[image]

Are there any settings I should do to make this flash fire when I take a shot with the camera? How does it even know that it should fire the flash?
This is a Nikon D-810 if you need some specific settings that I need to set in the camera.

Comment: Sorry, are you saying it's not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your camera doesn't have to "know" that the flash should fire when you're using a "dumb" (no TTL) flash; the hot shoe's centre-pin firing circuit is closed (turned on) when the shutter is open regardless of whether a flash is attached or not. All of the more complicated communications that happen for iTTL or manual CLS control happens through the other pins, which your manual flash doesn't have. The centre contact on the camera's shoe, though, is a much smaller and more fiddly target now than it was in the days before multi-contact TTL flashes, so you'll need to make sure that the flash trigger adapter (or wireless transmitter, should you decide to step up in the future) is properly seated in the hot shoe. From your set-up photograph, it looks like you haven't got the adapter far enough forward to properly engage the centre contact.

As for settings on the camera, all you really need to do is to make sure that you are in Manual mode (so that you have control over both your shutter speed for sync and ambient exposure and aperture for flash exposure and depth of field) and that your shutter speed is at or below your camera's X-sync speed (1/250 or slower).

Comment: --and that the LP180 is out of optical slave mode (the "So-OFF" on the LCD indicates this is set correctly). If the optical slave is turned on, the LP-180 ignores any signals from the foot and sync ports in favor of the optical sensor.